# Transparent QGLWidget on top of QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qglwidget

I'm using `QGraphicsView` to show a 2D image and also have a separate `QGLWidget` window to display some 3D object. I'm dynamically changing the image displayed in `QGraphicsView' based on the rotation of the 3D object.

I would like to render a semi-transparent 3D object on top of the 2D image, something like Maya 2009 used to do (notice the cube in the upper right corner of the viewport): [image: Maya 2009 screenshot]
<sub>(source: [boulevard-creation.com](http://www.boulevard-creation.com/images/2008/11/maya2009png.png))</sub>

Is it possible to do this with my current widgets? If not, how could it be done?

One option I can think of would be to render everything in `QGLWidget` and display the 2D image as a texture on a background plane, but that seems slightly painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way, but it is quite slow: you can simply add another `QGraphicsItem` to the `QGraphicsScene` like this
    `scene->addPixmap(glWidget->renderPixmap());`

Transparency can than be set with `QGraphicsItem::setOpacity()`.

There should be a faster way using `QPixelBuffer`, but I didn't manage to render to it properly yet.

Comment: This method properly invalidates your whole screen boring it to be re-rendered. This is why it might be slow for you

Answer (score 1):

Set the viewport of your qgraphicsview to the qglwidget, then in your paint method you can directly use gl calls to draw your 3d objects.

See http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting